# How: Communication between VB.NET web app and Web Connector (not QB Online)

Tags: .net, vb.net, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

The Intuit documentation does not make clear the solution path I need to take.  I hope that someone has done what I am trying to accomplish.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a web application written in VB.NET, deployed on a website with an SSL certificate.  This webserver (IIS/MSSQL/.NET) is on a VPN and is part of a local area network on which Quickbooks is installed.  The .qwc file resides on one of the internal LAN computers, and we have a Web Connector running on that machine.

I have installed through NuGet the Quickbooks IPP v3 API, into the VB.NET project.

That API (IPPv3) seems to push me into using code calls that start with connecting oAuth to the Quickbooks Online.  I am not using Quickbooks Online, but am wanting to communicate from the Web Connector to the web application we have on the https: URL.

Or something like that.  I'm not even sure if this is the best route to go.  Bottom line is that the company cannot use QB Online, but can run the web connector, authorized to expose "the books" to that application layer.

Do you have any pointers on how I can accomplish this?  Any sample online code?

Thank you for any help you might provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All development for the desktop will need to be done through the QBXML SDK.
https://developer.intuit.com/v2/docs/0250_qb

To connect to your web application, you will need to use the QB Web Connector (QBWC) included with QB desktop. There is a QBWC server sample included in the SDK along with programmer guides for QBXML and QBWC.

If you are using PHP, there is an open source project available that has the server built and sample requests.
http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/